# Open DropDown below the selected value flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]I need to to show dropdown below the selected value . How can we set Dropdown vertical offset in flutter like we do in android. is there a simple way to it without creating custom dropdown? image is attached and

Here is my drop down code:

```
  Container(
             width: percentWidth(77, context),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
                                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                    isExpanded: true,
                                    value: state.selectedSubject,
                                    underline: Container(
                                      height: 1.0,
                                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                          border: Border(
                                              bottom: BorderSide(
                                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                                  width: 0.0))),
                                    ),
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                    iconSize: 0,
                                    elevation: 16,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                                    onChanged: (String data) {
                                      _userFeedbackBloc
                                          .add(UserFeedbackEvent.onDropDownChanged(data));
                                    },
                                    items: spinnerItems.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                            (String newValue) {
                                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                            value: newValue,
                                            child: Text(newValue),
                                          );
                                        }).toList(),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, here use offset my friend.

```
offset: Offset(0, 100),
```

put that good Offset inside PopupMenuButton

Comment: should i use PopupMenuButton instead of  DropdownButton??

Comment: yup, but it takes a small customization to show the selected value like DropdownButton does.

Comment: Thanks.. i will try it.

Comment: @DwiKurniantoM could you please help where do I need to set the PopupMenuButton inside DropDownButton class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CustomDropDown

https://github.com/DhavalRKansara/CustomDropDown/blob/main/custom_drop_down.dart

Copy code from above line and past In dart file

Then you can use it like below

```
CustomDropdownButton(
                  value: _selectedCompany,
                  items: _dropdownMenuItems,
                  onChanged: onChangeDropdownItem,
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76899391/11566969) You don't have to use any external packages, just material package and menuStyle property.

```
menuStyle: const MenuStyle(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        maximumSize:
            MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size.fromHeight(Sizes.p124)))
```

Comment: This is for DropdownMenu, not DropdownButton

Comment: The title of the question and description doesn't ask for a specific class like DropdownButton, it's just about "DropDown" specific customizations. Which is what my answer provides.

Comment: The code snippet OP provided uses DropdownButton.

Comment: please read my previous comment, I know it is, but the question didn't specify what class to use